# iText throws ClassCastException: PdfNumber cannot be cast to PdfLiteral

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-reader

I am using iText v5.5.1 to read PDF and render paint text from it:

```
pdfReader = new PdfReader(new CloseShieldInputStream(is));
pdfParser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader);

int maxPageNumber = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
int pageNumber = 1;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

SimpleTextExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

while (pageNumber <= maxPageNumber) {
    pdfParser.processContent(pageNumber, extractionStrategy);

    sb.append(extractionStrategy.getText());

    pageNumber++;
}
```

On [one PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mu6gfkqjfqd4amj/itext_ClassCastException.pdf?dl=0) the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfNumber cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfLiteral
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.processContent(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:382)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.processContent(PdfReaderContentParser.java:80)
```

That PDF file seems to be broken, but maybe its contents still makes sense...

Comment: Is there supposed to be any visible content in that PDF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed

> That PDF file seems to be broken

The content streams of all pages look like this:

```
/GS1 gs
q
595.00 0 0
```

It looks like they all are cut off early as the last line is not a complete operation. This certainly can make a parser hickup as iText does.

Furthermore the content should be longer because even the size of their compressed stream is a bit larger than the length of this. This indicates streams broken on the byte level.

Looking at the bytes of the PDF file one cannot help but notice that

1. even inside binary streams the codes 13 and 10 only occur together and
2. cross-reference offset values are less than the actual positions.

So I assume that this PDF has been transmitted using a transport method handling it as textual data, especially replacing any kind of assumed line break (CR or LF or CR LF) with the CR LF now omnipresent in the file (CR = Carriage Return = 13; LF = Line Feed = 10). Such replacements will automatically break any compressed data stream like the content streams in your file.

Unfortunately, though...

> but maybe its contents still makes sense

Not much. There is one big image associated to each page respectively. Considering the small size of the content streams and the large image size I would assume that the PDF only contains scanned pages. But the images also are broken due to the replacements mentioned above.

Comment: You suggestion concerning CR/LF replacement is very nice, thanks. If you already know what could be the offset, maybe you could provide a cure? At least maybe you can tell me where exactly to extract these offsets and what values they should have, so that I can further experiment with CR←→LF translation. It seems that file needs very simple manipulation (remove CR or remove LF).

Comment: *It seems that file needs very simple manipulation (remove CR or remove LF).* - the cr and lf stuff was the *obvious* defect but there may be other defects, too. Thus, replacing each crlf by a cr or a lf may not fix the whole document. And you don't know what each crlf was before, it could have been a single cr, a single lf, or a crlf. Testing each variant will mean trying very very many variants.

Comment: You're right. I tried naive crlf→cr and one more time crlf→lf but still cannot open PDF. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution, but I had this exact problem and unfortunately can't share the exact PDFs I was having issues with.

I made a fork of itextpdf that catches the ClassCastException and just skips PdfObjects that it takes issue with. It prints to System.out what the text contained and what type itextpdf thinks it was. I haven't been able to map this out to some systemic problem with my PDFs (someone smarter than me will need to do that), and this exception only happens once in a blue moon. Anyway, in case it helps anyone, this fork at least doesn't crash your code, lets you parse the majority of your PDFs, and gives you a bit of info on what types of bytestrings seem to give itextpdf indigestion.

https://github.com/njhwang/itextpdf